# What's the best way to test older versions of IE on OSX?

Tags: windows, macos, testing, internet-explorer-7, virtual-machine

I need to test a web application on older versions of Internet Explorer. I'm running OSX El Capitan locally.

My preference is to run a local VM (Virtual Box or VMWare) rather than use a service like https://www.browserstack.com, although I'm open to any suggestions or recommendations.

What's the best way to test older versions of IE on OSX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download virtual machines with different versions of IE on them directly from Microsoft: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/

They have IE6 all the way up to Edge available. The virtual machines are available for VirtualBox, Vagrant, VMWare and Parallels.